# How to assign and array of type 'string[]' to an non empty array of type '[string, ...string[]]'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface defined as follows. It is part of a reusable NPM module. All works fine within the module, my unit tests work and I can create settings using `[ "value" ]`

```
export interface Settings {
  nonEmptyArrayProperty: [string, ...string[]]
}
```

However I have another module which imports this package and I am trying to define settings from within it. I get the following error:

```
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '[string, ...string[]]'.
```

My settings are in a js file but are identical in terms of property names:

```
export const SETTINGS= {
    nonEmptyArrayProperty: ["value1", "value"],
};
```

One thing to note is I am using the spread operator to convert the JS settings to the Settings interface defined in my library.

How do I assign a string[] to [string, ...string[]]?

Comment: I tried this in the TS Playground and it seems to work fine. Can you reproduce a minimal example? 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZWBhmQHMBnOAbwCg44kIkBRAWzBgE8BBKKTTgAUoEMGi4AuOAG1yMKGQA0cAHRq5CpKWkBdHTQC+NGtiZy45IiS3kphYmUoBeanQZM2HHnwHDR4zilpACIAN0wAGwBXYABGYOUwyJiAJmD9AwBuYyA

Comment: Okay, I think I kind of reproduced it. I solved it with `as const` and spreading the result. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZWBhmQHMBnOAbwCg44kIkBRAWzBgE8BBKKTTgAUoEMGi4AuOAG1yMKGQA0cAHRq5CpKWkBdHTQC+NGtiZy45IiS29+nOAF4ZAIgBumADYBXYAEZnym6ePgBMzjpwmJSmSHIA3MYx5pbEZORShKlalE609Iws7Fy2AsKi4pxS0moqKdakJZz6BnFAA

Comment: The reason typescript doesn't allow this is because the type `[string, [...string]]` means that the value contains at least one string, while `string[]` can contain 0. So when it comes to the line of assignment, typescript only knows it's a `string[]`, so it thinks it might be empty (event if it's obvious to us that it's not). By using `as const`, it won't infer the type as `string[]`, but instead as `[string, string]`, which it then can infer as `[string, ...string[]]`

Comment: @ShamPooSham I believe your comment should be an answer on this question

Comment: @ShamPooSham thanks for the example. I've tried what you have with no luck. My Settings interface is defined in a lib published to npmjs. I've inherited an application which has settings defined in a config.js file. This is then imported into a typescript file which maps the config,js SETTINGS object to the libraries Settings interface (it contains a few more values than the config.js).

Comment: TSC tells me the expected type comes from the lib but still throws the errors   Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '[string, ...string[]]'.
    Source provides no match for required element at position 0 in target.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter if the interface is from a library or not. Can you try to reproduce the issue with a minimal example? Either through ts playground or stackblitz (where you can easily add npm packages). As of now, I can't help you anymore because I can't reproduce your problem

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ujgskv?file=index.ts

Comment: Minus business logic thats exactly what I'm trying to do. Stackblitz is allowing type `any` to be assigned to the non empty array. Same tsconfig that I have here too.

Comment: Okay, so the issue is that your config file uses js which means that you can't type the values there. How about you use `as [string, ...string[]]` instead of `as const`? Note that this will just typecast for the compiler, and won't do anything in runtime. If you want to make sure that the config file includes has the correct format you have to put logic in for that manually.

Comment: Thats did the trick. Thanks. Not sure how to accept your comment as the answer

Comment: You're welcome :) I created an answer now, you can upvote and accept it if you like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason typescript doesn't allow this is because the type `[string, [...string]]` means that the value contains at least one string, while `string[]` can contain 0. So when it comes to the line of assignment, typescript only knows it's a `string[]`, so it thinks it might be empty (event if it's obvious to us that it's not).

If you specify the type of the variable you assign to the settings object beforehand, you won't come into this trouble. In typescript, this means you can do the following when assigning the variable:

```
const nonEmptyArray = ["value1", "value"] as const;
```

But if you do (as pointed out in the comments) get the variable from an untyped javascript file, you'll have to be more specific with the type, as follows:

```
export const SETTINGS= {
    nonEmptyArrayProperty: nonEmptyArray as [string, ...string[]],
};
```